# Equilibrium temperature in a heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

To find the equilibrium temperature distribution for a heat equation,
$$U(x,t)$$ it is critical to note that the second partial derivatives WRT the space variables is zero.

Why is this so?

Comment: What's the heat equation?

Comment: Does it matter?
In any case
$$\left.\frac{\text{$\delta $u}}{\text{$\delta $t}}\text{=K(}\frac{\delta
   ^2u}{\text{$\delta $x}^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, it matters, for what can you say about the left hand side if the right hand side is zero?

Comment: It implies that the change in the system U(x,t) (the heat equation in 2-D) is zero with respect to time.
But my point was, why is it necessary to set the second order partial derivative with respect to space equal to zero?

Comment: You answered your own question. If you still don't see it, I'm willing to spell it out for you in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

An equilibrium distribution is stationary, therefore it does not evolve over time

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = 0$$

Substituting this in the heat equation immediately leads us to

$$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2} = 0 \; .$$